# Congruence equation ...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I reduced the equation:

$84x \equiv 68\mod 400$

$21x \equiv 17\mod 100$

$100 = 4 \times 21 + 16$

$21 = 1 \times 16 + 5$

$16 = 3 \times 5 + 1$

so we have...

$16 = 100 - 4 \times 21$

$5 = 21 - 1 \times 16$

$1 = 16 - 3 \times 5$

Now, I need the equation in the form of $21v + 100w = 1$ and I have to find v and w

$1=16-3 \times 5$

$=16-3(21-1 \times 16)$

$=16 - 3 \times 21 +3 \times 16$

$=100 - 4 \times 21 -3 \times 21 +3 \times 16$

At this point I don't know what to do. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The congruence $84x \equiv 68 \pmod{400}$ means $84x = 68 + 400t$ for some integer $t$.  Dividing both sides of the equation by $4$ yields $21x = 17 + 100t$, so your conclusion that $21x \equiv 17 \pmod{100}$ is valid, if not fully justified. The reason it is useful to write the congruence in the form $21x \equiv 17 \pmod{100}$ is that $\gcd(21, 100) = 1$, so $21$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo $100$ and the congruence $21x \equiv 17 \pmod{100}$ has a unique solution.  We can find that solution by finding the multiplicative inverse of $21 \pmod{100}$.  To do so, we use the extended Euclidean algorithm.

You used the extended Euclidean algorithm to correctly obtain
$$1 = 16 - 3 \cdot 21 + 3 \cdot 16$$
which we can simplify as 
$$1 = 4 \cdot 16 - 3 \cdot 21$$
Since $16 = 100 - 4 \cdot 21$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
1 & = 4(100 - 4 \cdot 21) - 3 \cdot 21\\
  & = 4 \cdot 100 - 16 \cdot 21 - 3 \cdot 21\\
  & = 4 \cdot 100 - 19 \cdot 21
\end{align*}
Thus, $-19$ is the multiplicative inverse of $21 \pmod{100}$.  Multiplying both sides of the congruence $21x \equiv 17 \pmod{100}$ by $-19$ yields
$$x \equiv -323 \equiv -323 + 4 \cdot 100 \equiv 77 \pmod{100}$$
However, we want the solutions of the congruence $84x \equiv 68 \pmod{400}$.  Thus, we need all values of $x \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, 399\}$ that satisfy $x \equiv 77 \pmod{100}$.  Since $x \equiv 77 \pmod{100}$ means there exists an integer $k$ such that $x = 77 + 100k$.  If we take $k = 0, 1, 2, 3$, respectively, we obtain the solutions
\begin{align*}
x & \equiv 77 \pmod{400}\\
  & \equiv 177 \pmod{400}\\
  & \equiv 277 \pmod{400}\\
  & \equiv 377 \pmod{400}
\end{align*}
of the congruence $84x \equiv 68 \pmod{400}$. Notice that there are no more solutions since any other number that satisfies $x \equiv 77 \pmod{100}$ is equivalent to one of these four values modulo $400$.  For instance, if we take $k = 4$, we obtain $77 + 4 \cdot 100 \equiv 77 + 400 \equiv 77 \pmod{400}$.

**Check:**  $84 \cdot 77 \equiv 6468 \equiv 16 \cdot 400 + 68 \equiv 68 \pmod{400}$.  The other solutions can be checked similarly by direct substitution.

Comment: Why 1=16−3⋅21+3⋅16 becomes 1=4⋅16−3⋅21?

Comment: Observe that $16 - 3 \cdot 21 + 3 \cdot 16 = 1 \cdot 16 + 3 \cdot 16 - 3 \cdot 21 = 4 \cdot 16 - 3 \cdot 21$.

Comment: x≡−323≡77(mod100) What did you do here?

Comment: Observe that $-323 + 4 \cdot 100 = 77$.  Hence, $-323 \equiv 77 \pmod{100}$.

Comment: How did you find the solutions? What did you substitute?

Comment: By definition, $x \equiv 77 \pmod{100}$ means $x = 77 + 100k$ for some integer $k$.  Substituting $0, 1, 2, 3$ for $k$ give, respectively, $x = 77, 177, 277, 377$.  I stopped after $377$ since these are the only four values that are between $0$ and $399$ (the possible residue classes of $400$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71719/discussion-between-sdnaksn-and-n-f-taussig).